# Using AWS Directory Services AD to authenticate PC clients

Tags: aws-directory-service

We have an enterprise AWS Directory Services AD, and I'm wondering if it's possible/practical to use it as our AD for company desktop PC's, as well as for AWS resources.

We don't have resources to manage our own on-premise AD server etc. so would prefer to just keep everything in the cloud.

Does this sort of thing actually work? Is it a supported use-case for AWS Directory Services?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you can join windows 10 PCs to an AD Azure domain pretty easily. The'as really what Microsoft is pushing atm.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but we're using AWS AD, and cannot change to Azure. Also we have a mix of Windows 7 & 10, and Macs.